# How do I change fonts of plots in R and save it to a pdf?

Tags: r

I am trying to change the font of my R plots using the following commands:

```
windowsFonts(times = windowsFont("Times New Roman"))
par(family = "times")
```

I am using the basic plot (no ggplot etc), and notice that the changed font does not register when I save my R plot as a pdf (but it does register when saving as an image though). Is there a simple solution to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange but as I was playing around I ran the following two lines of code:

```
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)
```

After running the two lines of code, I tried saving the plot as a pdf again, and it turns out that the fonts have been registered. It would be nice if someone can explain why that happened.